# How to enable device choosing for my watch face?

Tags: wear-os, watchface

I have designed a watch face using Samsung Watch Face Studio. The output is an apk and aab file. When I directly upload it to the Google Store, it's not easily found by my customers.

I used the Answer from the link below and got a usable companion app and uploaded it as an aab too. So far, so good.
But here is where the problem starts. I can find my watch face when I search from a watch, I also find the companion app if I search with my phone, but if I look for a compatible watch face from the phone I can't find it in the play store.

The Goal would be that the User is able to choose the device he wants the watch face installed on. Other watch faces in the store allow for that behavior.

[Uploading my designed watch face to a watch using a companion app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75628405/uploading-my-designed-watch-face-to-a-watch-using-a-companion-app)

[My Watch Face](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.watchfacestudio.pixelartforest)